# How can I combine pandas groupby, apply and cumsum and into a single statement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I'm trying to combine the product expression used by a groupby/cumsum as the product's only purpose is to create a temporary holding value.

```
data = {
    'trial': pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]),
    'event': pd.Series(['A','A','A','B','B','B','C']),
    'weight': pd.Series([1,2,4,5,5,3,1]),
    'score': pd.Series([100,100,50,80,80,100,60])
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['tmp_product'] = df['weight'] * df['score']  # (1)
df['accum_product'] = df.groupby('event')['tmp_product'].cumsum()  # (2)
del df['tmp_product']
print(df.head())
```

---

```
   trial event  weight  score  accum_product
0      1     A       1    100            100
1      2     A       2    100            300
2      3     A       4     50            500
3      4     B       5     80            400
4      5     B       5     80            800
```

The above code does work but when I tried to combine #1 and #2 together it fails (like below):

```
df['accum_product'] = df.groupby('event').apply(lambda x: x['weight'] * x['score'], axis=1).cumsum()
```

Is there any solution to combine #1/#2 df expressions above?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`mul`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mul.html) and chain it with [`GroupBy.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.cumsum.html?highlight=cumsum#pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.cumsum) :

```
df["accum_product"] = df["weight"].mul(df["score"]).groupby(df["event"]).cumsum()
```

Or as suggested by @[*Chrysophylaxs*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9499196/chrysophylaxs), use [`eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html) :

```
 df["accum_product"] = df.eval("weight * score").groupby(df["event"]).cumsum()
```

​
Output :

```
print(df)
​
   trial event  weight  score  accum_product
0      1     A       1    100            100
1      2     A       2    100            300
2      3     A       4     50            500
3      4     B       5     80            400
4      5     B       5     80            800
5      6     B       3    100           1100
6      7     C       1     60             60
```

Comment: Too fast for me ;-)

Comment: Kind of cute alternative to mul would be to go `df.eval("weight * score")`

Comment: @Corralien, it's flattering, because it means we have reflected on the same approach ;) @Chrysophylaxs, we tend to forget about *pandas'* `eval`. I updated my answer and thanks ;)

Comment: Wow, both answers work and help me to better understanding pandas. I'm leaning towards @Chrysophylaxs solution .. as its a tad less wordy.

Comment: If I can add a follow-up clarification question?  Why do you need to make the groupby argument a series, eg groupby(df["event"]), vs just using the column name 'event'?